# load page freshly and not from cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, browser-cache

Is there way I can force page not to load from cache? Everytime page is loaded it is loaded from server.
I'm using asp.net MVC 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a custom no cache action filter:

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{  
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        cache.SetNoStore();
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then decorate any controller/action with this attribute that you don't want to be cached by client browsers.

Comment: How about the JS files CSS files referred in the view for an action? will they get loaded every time if i put this on a action?

Comment: The static resources are directly served by IIS. They are not even reaching your application code.