# ASP.NET Browser Cache Expiry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I would like to turn off browser caching for my site and set a date in the past for expiry.

I have followed the answer in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406003/how-do-i-turn-off-caching-for-my-entire-asp-net-mvc-3-website) which has left me with almost perfect results, however I always get back a -1 for cache expiry, even after setting a date in the past.

If i remove the:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

the previous date is set in my header (although caching is still enabled).

I am led to believe that an " actual expiry date" is required over a "-1" because of an issue with IE (could still cache the page).

Is .net overwriting the SetExpires with a -1 if the HttpCacheability.NoCache is set?

Comment: You can check this resource out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache.  You can also use filter actions.

Comment: thanks, followed that and still got the -1, just have to assume .net does some form of overwriting.

Comment: Try this, it looks pretty good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017560/load-page-freshly-and-not-from-cache