# how to disable cache when using User.IsInRole()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, windows-authentication, authorize-attribute

I created a new AD group "IT Dev".  the application only use windows authentication.  I am using User.IsInRole to check if user is in "IT Dev" group.

I couldn't get it work, it always return false. even tho, I already added myself to that group.

I used following codes to see what roles I am in. "IT Dev" is not there.

```
var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);

foreach (string rolesForUser in roles)
{
    var m = rolesForUser;
}
```

then, I restart my computer, everything works.  After it goes to production, I dont want to restart my computer, everytime i add a new group. how do I disable cache? so this role info is not saved on the server.

Comment: you can see this link for a reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017560/load-page-freshly-and-not-from-cache if it is helpful to you.

Comment: that is for attribute, but not User.IsInRole() function.